# Merchandising, merchandising, merchandising!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, t-shirt, merchandise, shop

If there was a `store.stackoverflow.com` I would love to buy T-Shirts, coffee cups, and (obviously) flamethrowers.

With Stackoverflow's newfound moola and near infinite talent, I bet this would be pretty doable (and profitable).

[image]

Comment: +1 for the flamethrowers reference; best line in that whole movie

Comment: @Pop: A strong contender, to be sure. But the competition is stiff: *"Funny, she doesn't _look_ Drewish."*  *"I've got the same combination on my luggage."* , *"What's the matter, Colonel Sanders? Chickennn?"*...

Comment: *I see your Schwartz is as big as mine*

Comment: Branded Unicorns - that is all. Oh an T-Shirts. I want a T-Shirt and a branded Unicorn.

Comment: I want a SF coffee mug.  http://serverfault.com/questions/29665/morning-rituals/29683#29683 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37493/what-do-stack-overflow-users-like-for-breakfast/37499#37499

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of Stack Exchange & community swag do you want](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those people trying to find the store who are as puzzled as I was: it is

<s>http://store.stackexchange.com/</s>

> EDIT: the SE shop [has closed permanently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Answer (score 4):

T-shirts featuring:

1. Stackoverflow logo $20
2. Joel - free
3. Jeff - we pay you $10
4. Taco $30

Comment: Taco? More like waffle

Comment: @Corey: [Taco](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/)

Comment: +1 For Taco, and his recurrences in the blog. @Joel, more Taco!

Comment: I'm in the market for a Coding Horror bobble-head.