# What kind of Stack Exchange & community swag do you want

Tags: discussion, swag

We're looking at getting some great new swag for community members, so we want to know, what stuff do you want to see?

We'll be making this all available with both Stack Exchange branding and all of the individual sites.

Suggestions we already have include:

- Laptop bags/sleeves
- Mugs/Pint Glasses
- Baby Onesies
- T-shirts

Suggest whatever things you'd like to see (even if it's only for one site) and upvote the really great suggestions so we know you all love them!

Comment: Who is this Alex Miller guy? :P

Comment: Reference: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=swag  :)

Comment: Why so many mugs?

Comment: @Robert New secret hire.  Very hush, hush.  Please to not retweet.

Comment: I prefer $10,000 in small bills wrapped in plain brown paper with an SO sticker affixed.  I'm assuming these are freebies, too. :-)

Comment: @theChrisKent - if you had a child that fit in a onesie you wouldn't be asking why you need so many mugs.

Comment: How about adult sized onesies?  I find them quite comfy.

Comment: Is buying ThinkGeek out of the question? I know you guys have all this VC money burning a hole in your pocket...

Comment: @Jay: FGITW SPEEDSUITS!

Comment: @Jay Riggs, It's times like this that I wish I could downvote comments. LOL

Comment: I would definitely purchase a Stackoverflow coffee cup.

Comment: If you make mugs PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE make them at least 16 oz with big handles!  I'd buy a boatload of them.

Comment: Yeah, what @squillman said. **LARGE** BEVERAGE CONTAINERS. In fact, let's skip mugs and pints entirely, go for tankards / schooners.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/what-types-of-stack-overflow-schwag-would-you-like-to-see

Comment: Since you guys have a home brewer in the family now, why not "Stack Ale?" :) [ducks]

Comment: @Shog the Stack Overflow ale tanker will soon be docking in a port near you!

Comment: I don't know if this is important or not but what is [this](http://store.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Careful, there's a [promotional content suspension](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-account/89027#89027) now! ;-)

Comment: On the Mug front: A good high capacity travel mug with a lid. Some of us need to drink our coffee on the move!

Comment: They should sell [hats!!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131436/156722)

Comment: As the store is no more, I'm closing this.

Comment: @TimPost when the store closed, one of the positive side effects the team cited was that swag would be perceived as more valuable if it had to be earned, so I disagree with your specific close reason.

Comment: Money. Cash. Dollars.

Answer (score 68):

A tinted half slinky coming out of a grey box!

[image]

The box would have to be less tall, and the spring would have to be painted in a brighter orange gradient. But you get the idea.

Comment: +1 for original thinking!

Comment: For a moment I thought SO's logo was a slinky :s

Answer (score 27):

- Rub-on tattoos! (I'm not kidding about the exclamation point here, I really am this excited about the prospect).
- [I really like the **JIT business cards** talked about on The Daiyly WTF yesterday](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/JustInTime-Business-Cards.aspx). Steal it?
- Sunscreen to protect our developer skin from the sun.
- Umbrella, to protect our clever heads from the rain.

[image]

Comment: +1 for JIT business cards.

Comment: But that umbrella would be closed as off-topic. :(

Comment: you can get some JIT business cards, free, at http://inedo.com/company/swag/just-in-time-business-cards

Comment: @Bobby Now I have a great excuse for next time I arrive at work soaking wet.

Answer (score 18):

http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/warfare/8a0f/

[image]

With StackOverflow stenciled on the webcam, of course. :P

Let the games begin!

Comment: I need the darts to say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask so I can shoot them at coworkers in response to their questions

Comment: +1 Oh yeah! Gotta have one of these.

Comment: omg, is that thing controllable from some sort of web interface?

Answer (score 18):

Some thoughts off the top of my head:

#### Clothing

- SO or SE branded clothes from [ScotteVest](http://www.scottevest.com/company/corporate_sales.shtml).
- It used to be that tech events only had t-shirts in sizes L, XL, and XXL. Women like me yelled enough so that they now go to their shirt jobbers and say, "Give me shirts for girls, too." So these days, tech events have t-shirts that fit Men's L, XL, and XXL, *and* t-shirts that fit girls ages 7 through 11. Be different; please order shirts in *Women*'s sizes, too!

  - Best of all would be v-neck shirts. *Nobody* has v-necks…
- I'd love a baseball cap. *Not* a trucker hat (okay, if someone else wants one, fine—but *I* want a baseball cap).

#### Tech stuff

- Forget mouse pads; I don't even know anyone who uses one any more.
- Any kind of carry bag is great. Messenger bags and backpacks are both good. Small gadget bags would be wonderful. Something like the [Cocoon Grid-It System](http://www.cocooninnovations.com/grid.php) would be *amazing*.
- Bizarre USB gadgets are always fun.

#### Household

- Good coffee mugs are great. Not just the small ceramic ones (although those are okay), but the type Starbucks sells are best.
- Flashlights. Everyone always needs flashlights.

Comment: +1 for stressing women's sizes. I can't tell you how fed up I am with corporate polo shirts that are big enough for me to wear as a dress. Also, for those of you in charge of swag, when we say women's sizes, we don't just mean smaller, we actually mean "shirts with cuts that fit women". Don't just order men's shirts in XS, noone except small guys will ever wear them.

Comment: +1 v-neck women's t-shirts.

Comment: I want a tumbleweed badge t-shirt.

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to have a set of business cards with the website logo and URL and the tagline so when I go to conferences I can hand them out to people for mass effect.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Answer (score 13):

1. BADGES - this is one of the essences of SO community - pin-on kind we can wear, put on our backpacks, etc.; stickers for our laptops / computers, bumper stickers for our cars, and tattoos.
2. Mousepads. Awesome ones.
3. Phone / iPhone and tablet / iPad cases - like what you see on http://www.getuncommon.com/

Comment: Unicorn [Head Badges](http://www.headbadges.com/catalog/c5_p1.html)!

Comment: badges would be awesome, and a cool inside joke! +1

Comment: I guess since now the fanatic badge has a completely different meaning to me

Answer (score 13):

Branded inflatable unicorns, of course!

[image: Inflatable Unicorns]

See [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004GBGF8A).

Comment: Yes. Filled with Helium, so it can fly across the land.

Comment: @Pekka - I was thinking _hydrogen_ actually ... after all, you're _supposed_ to 'blow them up' :)

Answer (score 12):

Bumper Stickers

Comment: +1, See revisions for good time.

Comment: Yes, but bicycles.SE should get stickers sized appropriately for affixing to the tubes of a bicycle frame. (smallest dimension smaller than 2".  horizontal layout and/or vertical layout).

Comment: `How's my coding? http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @Pekka: You made me LOL :D

Comment: +1, Definitely could double as a computer sticker - put one on a chassis for a desktop or the back of a laptop, anyone?

Answer (score 10):

Sweaters or hoodies. That's about all I can add (for once I hate the "at least 30 characters" rule)

Answer (score 9):

A USB thumb drive................

Comment: ... As nice as they are, I haven't seen any (reasonably priced) good branded ones... Nearly every branded/promotional stick I have got from a trade show are cheap/slow and break after you use them a bit... Not saying I would say no to one, but I would rather have a few hundred stickers or a t-shirt for the price of one stick!

Answer (score 9):

I want a real unicorn.

[image: real unicorn]

Comment: This is a unicow.

Comment: It's a *tricow.*

Answer (score 9):

**I think they should sell Stackoverflow hats!!!**
[image: White Stackoverflow hat]
[image: Black Stackoverflow hat]

Comment: I would absolutely buy the black one.

Answer (score 8):

Baseball caps. Or really, any kind of branded hat; I'd go for a SO Sombrero to go with my increasingly-listless rep graph...

Comment: I've found it's a side effect of SE employment—rough, eh?

Answer (score 7):

Mouse pads for any computer or gaming related site.

Comment: I didn't think people still _used_ mouse pads .. wow :)

Comment: @Tim, actually I don't have one at work.  It just sounded like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

A branded 'Easy' button, for questioners, answerers and general office use:
[image: Stack Overflow Easy Button!]

Yes, I know, my Paint skills are ***the*** best, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be in favour of something nice, original and small  to attach to your monitor or laptop case, preferably without the logo so it's not too obvious. A mascot of sorts, with a clip mechanism allowing it to be attached to any object of a certain width. I thought of Homer Simpson's [Springy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmldR.jpg) because of the SO logo's resemblance of a spring. Or something to that effect.

A nice little insider gag for people to talk about, and do a tiny little bit of bragging. Say for example, every user gets one once they surpass 10k rep. So if you see a guy with a SO mascot on their laptop case, you know they're a fellow stackhead.

Answer (score 5):

Some things I would like:

- [carabiners](http://www.google.com/images?q=carabiner&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=en&tab=wi&biw=1440&bih=757) (these things are so handy, you can put them anywhere)
- pens/pencils/markers
- [Nalgenes](http://www.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1440&bih=757&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=nalgene&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=)/water bottles branded with the logo
- keychain thingy
- knife with logo on the blade

Comment: I had to Google carabiners & Nalgenes to see what they meant =.=

Comment: sorry @Sathya, clarified...

Comment: Carabiners with *bottle openers* like this: http://www.sierranevadagiftshop.com/bar-supplies/bottle-openers/sierra-nevada-carabiner-bottle-opener.html

Answer (score 5):

Just send me a nice-looking share certificate that I can hang on a wall somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

What swag is complete without small, magical unicorn toys adorned with the SO logo?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Anything that has my flair (name, avatar, reputation, and badge counts) on it.

I love seeing that.

Comment: Hmmm, badge count, that asks for something with a little display and wifi connection...

Comment: @Arjan - Heh. While that would be awesome, I wouldn't mind if it became out-of-date.

Comment: Surely someone could change [this alarm clock](http://www.ambientdevices.com/products/flurry/) to show reputation, and above all: wake you up when you're downvoted, or wake you up an hour earlier if reputation growth is too low! (Or [a chumby](http://www.chumby.com/) or something like that.)

Answer (score 4):

Since the holidays are coming up soon, why not finally give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) and its answers (10k+ only, sorry) a proper place in Stack Overflow history by using it to print wrapping paper? It could be sold in packs of 10 sheets at an appropriate size to wrap the average gift.

Answer (score 3):

- Pens / Mechanical Pencils
- Keychains
- Snuggie / Slanket

Comment: +1 for keychains, but -1 for snuggies.  Total net rep gain: 0

Comment: -2 for snuggies, +1 for the others.  Same net gain.

Comment: It was a joke!! lol

Comment: +1 just for the Snuggie

Answer (score 3):

Customized high-quality business cards might be an interesting guerrilla way to promote the careers site.

Say, give every user above a certain reputation (or something) the chance to order a 100 pack of really high-quality (embossed?) business cards. They can define the contents themselves, with the condition that the web link points to their SO careers profile.

Comment: I want business cards as a moderator, to advertise SU or some other SE site...

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for T-shirts with *small* logos. (I dislike all my tech T-shirts with huge logos, I don't mind being an advertisement, but I don't really want to be a whore. :)

Also, *static* vinyl car window stickers. Something that can be easily removed and won't leave a gigantic pile of adhesive gunk. Something that sticks on the *inside* of windows, so it looks good for years.

And another +1 for business cards. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few creative suggestions:

- Posters (large ones preferably)
- StackOverflow pencils! (and pens)
- Soccer balls (I'd settle for ping-pong balls)
- Socks, ballcaps, jackets, etc.
- Plates (or other dishes)

Comment: socks?! dishes?! +1 for  the laugh :P

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Iron-on Appliques. Some may be designed to look like the gold/silver/bronze badges that we earn.
2. Not just ordinary T-shirts, but T-shirts with silly programmers' or geek proverbs.
3. T-shirts with much larger logo than the one already available.

Answer (score 2):

What about a rublik's cube, with logo's of six SE sides.

Comment: Well apart from the obvious trademark infringement, that does sound like a pretty good idea... providing the colors are solid.

Answer (score 2):

Whiteboard related Stuff like :

- Whiteboard Markers
- Whiteboard Eraser
- Whiteboard Cleaner
- [This Wonderful tool](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28356/how-to-clean-the-whiteboard/28361#28361) (10K-only on programmers-SE)

Answer (score 1):

iDevice cases with StackOverflow logo on the back.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to get an Etch-A-Sketch in the flavor of our favorite site?

[image: before-whiteboards]

I thought of this today while saying "*I'm working on getting the idea out of the Etch-A-Sketch phase into something more concrete.*"

Really though, the user interface to an Etch-A-Sketch is just beautiful.

Additionally the device doesn't require batteries, just frequent violent shaking, which most of us do to similar but far more modern devices daily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sue these guys for stealing what it should be a SO exclusive:

[image: Unicorn card reader]
<sub>(source: [vip-stores.com](http://c1.vip-stores.com/img/4-45639826-0-1-1))</sub>

### Tribal Pegasus Unicorn Memory Card Reader (Square)

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100670/should-a-free-t-shirt-badge-or-privilege-be-created/100697#100697)...

A Stack Overflow t-shirt with

- a small Stack Overflow logo on the left breast
- your badge list on one sleeve
- your reputation on the other sleeve
- optional Stack Exchange flair on the back

Comment: Any more stuff on it and people will think I joined the Girl Scouts!

Comment: You know, I never thought of it that way, but you do have a point.  :)  Of course, I was just envisioning the type and number of badges, which I thought would look fairly inconspicuous, rather than complete descriptions...

Answer (score 0):

"Hmm... **Shog in [a] box**... not a bad idea for the SE store." -[Tim Post ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) ([source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/710390#710390))

Answer (score 0):

For Writers.SE, I [suggested](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/motivational-humorous-posters-as-promotional-freebie) making motivational posters with inspiring and/or humorous quotes on them. I think if we had some good ones, a lot of new writers would think they were a cool think to have up in their writing workspace.

This idea might be applicable to other sites too (plenty of programmer humor out there...).

Answer (score 0):

I just want a regular **t-shirt**. No possibility to buy it right now.

Comment: IOW, bring back the store?

Comment: @TimPost: I've read already about the reasons to close the shop but on other hand still want to buy there. Nobody on internet offers SO t-shirts, or at least I haven't found them.