# Can Stack Overflow please get kiip advertising?

Tags: feature-request, advertising

The idea is that you get a real life reward for reaching an achievement, i.e. when you get a badge or reach a reputation milestone.

Kiip is actually targeting people playing games on their phones - giving you something for achieving something in the game. I think people achieving something on SO are more deserving than people achieving something in a game..

http://techcrunch.com/2011/04/10/kiip-is-an-entirely-new-mobile-ad-model-real-life-rewards-for-in-game-achievements/

Comment: What do ads have to do with badges?

Comment: When you get a badge an advertiser gets the opportunity to reward you with something which is advertising for their brand when you are happy.

Comment: Then potential rewarding would become more scarce the more you contributed to the site, given the 'reduced ads' model. So this is just an incentive for newcomers? Not sure people would like this idea, let alone _that_ angle.

Comment: I don't think the 'reduced ads' privilege should change this type of advertising because as you said it should be an incentive for all. In stead I think you should be allowed to opt out of receiving free gifts in your preference settings.

Comment: @Mr.Dis, I think this is for badge earners and would not be something that would be eliminated with the "reduced ads" feature.

Comment: So, you don't need to see the ad to receive a reward from the publisher?

Comment: You will see a link to get a reward.

Comment: Next time I'm out on the street, I'm definitely going to come up with a "Will code for mascara" placard.

Comment: @JonSkeet: We already know you do -- http://i.imgur.com/LOa5b.jpg

Comment: Actually, I'm interested by this and support investigating it further.  Unless I actually have to do so.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting idea.  However, I think it would be difficult to find advertisers that are able and want to give free samples to the badge recipients on SO, since they are typically a specific user group.

Furthermore, free sample or not, I don't think I would want to see an ad every time I got a badge. I am opposed to this change.

Comment: This is the whole business model of kiip - to find willing advertisers. All the metadata that SO has makes it ideal for tailor made promotions that you actually want eg. some free subscription to a magazine about the stuff you ask a lot of questions.

Comment: @AmanicA, that is true.  But either way, I don't want to see ads with badges.  If there was a separate rewards center where you could trade badges for free stuff that might be ok, because I could just not visit it if I didn't want to.

Comment: Maybe it should not be linked to badges, but to certain reputation milestones.

Comment: I think you'd find quite a few who would be willing to offer licenses for specific tags.  Like a license to a winforms graph control, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, to me this would cheapen the sites.  We're not in it for rewards or freebies (ok, [certain items aside](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want)), we're in it to help others and to learn.  I understand the need for advertising, but this is a bit too pushy for me, even if I'd be getting some kind of freebie.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but you must have put in effort to get to 6k reputation. I just thought it will be nice to get rewarded in the real life too - not just with some number on a website.

Comment: @AmanicA To me, helping others is its own reward. The number is nice, but I don't see it as a reward.

Comment: This _is_ <strike>SPARTAAAAAA!</strike> REAL LIFEEEE!

Answer (score 1):

There's already a way for advertisers to show ads only to 10k users (there's been at least one free software thing as a "reward" for hitting 10k); I'd be fine with extending that to other rep limits or particular badges (tag badges sound particularly useful, since development software is probably language-specific). If you're talking about an actual popup when you get a badge that tries to sell you something, that's probably going too far; I'm not certain which model you're proposing

Comment: As I understand it this is for brand marketing, so they should not be trying to sell you something but give you something if you have earned it. This type of marketing I saw was originally for giving you stuff if you achieve something while playing a game on your smart phone. This made me think though that people on SO is more deserving of a reward.

Comment: @Amanica Ok, as long as it's not those annoying full-screen popups like in the screenshots in the article you linked. I assume that's why you're getting downvoted so much, since this doesn't seem like a bad idea