# Stack Exchange Store now in Beta

Tags: discussion, t-shirt, merchandise, stickers, shop

> ### Update: [The store is closed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store/137580#137580).

As you may have noticed, [Alex M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159928/alex-miller) has been working on [more awesome swag items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want).

The fruits of his labor are now ready for **a public beta at http://store.stackexchange.com** where you can get your hands on this swag.

Please test the store out—it is fully functional, meaning, if you place an order, you should get it! If you have any feedback on the store, the ordering process, or more swag items we need, let us know.

We are currently working on:

- custom shirts and stickers for a new Stack Exchange 2.0 site each month. Yes we will eventually get all of them, but they will be "special editions" each month and can sell out.
- blue retractable Stack Exchange sharpies
- blue Stack Exchange whiteboard markers

We are still a bit low on stock on store items, so things may sell out while we reorder over the near term. That's why this is a public beta for meta folks only at the moment... once the store is fully stocked and tweaked, we will announce it on the blog.

[image: screenshot of StackExchange store]

Comment: Does the SO Hoodie really have a picture of a unicorn on it? >_>

Comment: Yes, please confirm the unicorn hoodie validity. Real picture with a model or it didn't happen.

Comment: I want to know who the shirt models are.

Comment: The shirt models are all folks from our NY office

Comment: No rep bags ...

Comment: @Alex great work! May I ask if the quality of the T-shirts is high as the old T-shirts sold on the first experimental [site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/does-buying-stack-overflow-t-shirt-from-amazon-work)? I have two of them and the quality is superb.

Comment: Yep, t-shirt quality is the same

Comment: No more store folks, just an FYI.

Answer (score 9):

Can you make it clearer about shipping?

e.g. how much is shipping?  Is it a flat rate *per* product, or or an *entire* order, etc

Comment: all elected (Trilogy) moderators should get t-shirts already; if they haven't, contact us for one!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - was actually an old system, we're now calculating shipping automatically based so no more flat rate charges.

Comment: I'd rather have that drinking bottle to complete my collecting of swag!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I hate you all.

<sub>Can I get an email or something when they're back? <sup><sub>I'm just going to keep hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> otherwise</sub></sup></sub>

Comment: the solution is clear: get bigger.

Comment: Curse you, genetics!

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Shrink-a-Cotton-T-Shirt. YMMV.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately as Jeff mentioned we are low in stock (or out) of certain items.  Fortunately all of these are on order so we should have full stock of all t-shirt sizes by next week

Answer (score 3):

It won't let me purchase from here in the UK:

```
Error from gateway:

This transaction cannot be accepted
```

Just tried again with a different card. Both Visa, first one was a credit card, second a regular debit card.

Bummer. And they'll be going like hot cakes...

Comment: Alex Miller is working on it.I get the same thing.

Comment: This should be all fixed now - please try again and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: _'Thank you for shopping at Stack Exchange.'_ Consider me forever indebted to you.