# Provide package tracking code for store purchases

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, shop, t-shirt

I recently placed an order on the [Stack Exchange Online Store](http://store.stackexchange.com/) <sup>*[beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87402/stack-exchange-store-now-in-beta)*</sup>. I received a friendly confirmation email, but no estimate of when my merchandise would arrive or any sort of tracking mechanism. It would be nice if we could be provided with a FedEx or UPS or USPS or whatever you use tracking code so that we could anxiously refresh a webpage hoping that our highly anticipated loot will arrive sooner if we can see where in Tennessee it's sitting on a truck.

[image: xkcd reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been implemented. I ordered a shirt on August 21st, and received this email:

> Dear *`name`*,
>
> The following shipped items from order #*`n`* have been updated with
>   new shipping information:
>
> 1x Super User T-Shirt - Medium / White
>
> They are being shipped via *`shipping service`* with tracking number
>   *`##########`*. You can see the status of this shipment at the
>   following URL:
>
> *`http://example.com/track/#######`*
>
> Please allow some time for the status of the shipment to correctly
>   display at the above address.