# Where can I find shipping information for the Stack Exchange store?

Tags: support, shop

I can't seem to find any information about shipping on the SE store. Specifically international shipping. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87402/stack-exchange-store-now-in-beta/87403#87403) appears to have been edited into a question, unsurprisingly with no answer left in a comment.

Do they ship internationally, and if so, how much does it cost? Are multiple items shipped in bulk or would I have to pay per item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do ship internationally, IIRC it was <s>$6.</s>

Seems it varies from item to item.

[image]

[image]