# What's up with the shipping rates on the Stack Exchange store?

Tags: discussion, shop

And I mean $40 shipping for a $15 T-shirt?

[image]

I have this image here from a previous quote(didn't place it then) where 2xbeer steins and a T-shirt resulted in $24 shipping.. which is reasonable considering the items, but, golly $40 for a T-shirt?

[image]

Rebecca Chernoff [mentions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3092789#3092789)

> if your subtotal is $0 you should have a free shipping option.

... and from the above screenshot you can see even with the coupon applied, I'm asked to pay for the shipping.

I know I live on the other side of the world, but does it really cost this much? If so, how come earlier the shipping prices [were *much* lesser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94479/133693)?

---

Alex Miller says there should be an option for free shipping, there isn't.

[image]

Comment: Does the free shipping option only allow carrier pigeon or slow boat to China?

Comment: Can I upgrade to African or European Swallow for a bit extra?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment that's understandable for the glass - but the image and my question talks about a single t-shirt

Comment: Just reproduced to the UK out of curiosity: http://i.imgur.com/fmMzb.png _Ahhh!_ Won't be renewing mine for a good while.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment oh wow!

Comment: Y'all forgot to enter the discount code "OMGWTFLOL"

Comment: So, $40 for [bubble wrap which costs $16 for like, 100'](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202029367/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)?  Yeah, but no.

Comment: @Sathya can you email me directly about the issue with the free shipping option not showing up? shop@stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE:** Upon further investigation, it appears that USPS changed their APIs and was not returning all of the appropriate rates (namely the least expensive ones).  We've fixed the issue and you can now get cheap shipping again!

---

There's a couple questions in here, so I'll address them each:

1. **Yes, it really does cost this much.**  All our shipping prices are calculated automatically by USPS and Fedex.  Our system tells them the shipping zip code, the destination address and the weight of the package, and their system feeds back the price.
2. As for the free shipping: If you have a discount code that brings your total down to $0, then an option for free shipping is available in the dropdown.  It is NOT selected by default, but you can select it if you click the dropdown menu.  When free shipping is selected, we ship it by standard international first class mail.
3. As for why the price changed, I can't tell you that without knowing exactly when you got each quote.  The system was, for a brief time, incorrectly charging too little for shipping (which has since been corrected).  It's also possible that USPS changed their prices.

Comment: It appears that USPS did in fact change their shipping prices for flat rate boxes sometime early January.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. With the shipping rates as high as these, I'm not sure if it's going to be feasible. Not that I'm saying SE Inc., should bear the shipping rate. WRT #2: You can see, I have applied a code which brings down the amount to zero, yet the free shipping option is not available. http://i.imgur.com/maywL.png

Comment: With those kinds of shipping prices, I think it would be cheaper to sell us licenses to print our own :)

Comment: This seems highly unreasonable. I can by any t-shirt, sweater, etc. from Ebay for less than $10 delivery, worldwide, or a pair of cowboy boots from Sheplers for ~$30 (~5 lbs). $42 (for a piece of clothe) is just ridiculous.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment can you email me (shop@stackexchange.com) with the details of your order there.  There should be a cheaper option (USPS First Class) showing up that would substantially less