# Can we get a Stack Overflow meme sticker?

Tags: discussion, community

I know that some of the top users got their [T-shirts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition) and the some of the rest of us got stickers for participating in the survey but can we get a meme sticker? As described in the [Trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) I cannot do it on my own right?

> Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc

Does the unicorn shaped *"answer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/%22)* [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3k41.png) constitute as needing permission to use it as a self made sticker?

You cannot? wear the t-shirt everyday but you can bet your waffles your laptop/car/cat will have [swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115520/147778) all day.

Comment: I'd try "Can has stikkurz kthxbye"

Comment: I still wish I could buy that t-shirt.

Comment: "unicorn shaped answer" - did I miss something? Is bobince's answer one of those "stare-at-for-boat" pictures?

Comment: @Kev unicorn shaped "answer thingie" logo

Comment: @phwd - lol ok, didn't notice "logo" was a different link...just wasted a whole hour staring at bobince's answer waiting for a unicorn to magically appear :D

Comment: I like memes. meme all the things!

Comment: @MatthewRead But not if [it costs an arm and a leg](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119980/whats-up-with-the-shipping-rates-on-the-stack-exchange-store/). Sad times :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could always make a T-shirt that says TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: Robert I have just become a JSE moderator and I have a Joomla conference next week where I am going to be presenting a Joomla Stack Exchange workshop.  I want to hand out JSE stickers, but I don't have enough time to wait for bureaucratic wheels to turn and stickers to be delivered.  Is there a direct line that I can take to get swift approval to have these generated externally (local to Brisbane)?  I guess I only need permission and the official JSE image file because I have someone locally that can produce the 100 stickers.  Can you advise?

Comment: @mickmackusa: I suggest you ask one of the CM's in the Teacher's Lounge.