# Which parts of Stack Exchange cost money?

Tags: support, terms-of-service, business-model, cost

I was reading through the [Public Network Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public). What does the following passage refer to?

> - Some premium or additional features of Stack Overflow (including without limitation Stack Overflow for Teams) may require a payment obligation for access and use. You are solely responsible for ensuring that your payment obligations, if any, remain current and not in arrears. In the event Stack Overflow charges for features you will be clearly notified of the terms of any payment obligations and provided the opportunity to refuse such obligations before you incur any charges. Please note, however, that your refusal to accept payment obligations may result in your inability to access or use certain premium or additional features of Stack Overflow.

What "premium or additional features" exactly cost money?

Comment: The advertisements.  And asking questions in meta, one dollar please.

Comment: I thought you can buy a private server install license of StackExchange? For example, you buy a FogBugz license to install on your own server.

Comment: @Sun you can buy Enterprise version of Stack Overflow, yes. https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do some companies pay for a dedicated Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313406/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79435/282094

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parts of http://careers.stackoverflow.com and of course http://jobs.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 5):

The awesome [merchandise](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)! ;)

Comment: They really implemented the Beer stein? No *way*.

Comment: _Way_! Would have much preferred [the Easy button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want/87460#87460), but alas...

Comment: Ironically, very disappointing that the merch store is still closed.....@Mr.Disappointment

Answer (score 5):

The parts that cost money are listed under "Products" in Stack Overflow:

> [image: Stack Overflow list of products]

Namely:

- Teams
- Enterprise
- Talent
- Advertising

The Q&A sites are free to use.