# Should a free t-shirt badge or privilege be created?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, t-shirt

From what I could tell this doesn't exist, but I think its reasonable considering that answering questions indirectly generates revenue right?

A free SO shirt (just a plain one from the [shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)) at some amount of points or for satisfying some badge requirement.

Should it be created?

Comment: What about a pony? I want a pony!

Comment: pony would be nice too, but a shirt would be cool.

Comment: But where are we gonna get the funds for these shirts?  How about we start charging for these answers we have here.

Comment: Waffles.  Mmmm.... Waffles.

Comment: Oh oh oh! I know what we can do!!! First we let Google index the sites, so that people find out that we have theyre answers!!! Oh, this is gonna be sooooo good, trust me! And then, and then, when people come visit our site, we show blurry text, indicating that the answers are here, juuuust out of reach. Then, and then, we charge them for a membership, so that they can see the actual answers! How's that for a greeeat! idea? Then we could all have T-shirts, zomg!

Comment: Also, my cat (http://www.flickr.com/photos/lassevk/4831217311/in/set-72157624588026786) doesn't like ponies, so that's *completely* out of the question!

Comment: @Lasse: Yeah, but then we'd have to put a hyphen in the site's URL.

Comment: Drat, those dreaded hyphens. Ok, forget *that* then.

Comment: Why ponies? Unicornzz!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some SE 2.0 sites (Programmers, Gaming, others?) have had some [swag given out](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) to top users.

I suspect it's a one-time deal when the sites are young, though. I don't think it's feasible to do something like that either repeatedly or on larger, more established sites now.

Comment: SO did that at some point, they sent out free T-shirts to all users on the first 3 pages of users, sorted by reputation, that's how I got mine. Oh, and of course we all remember [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: cool. I guess it works better as a special thing. Probably isn't easy to scale to all of SO. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the funds involved, I don't think a T-shirt or similar swag when you reached a certain rep threshold would be unwelcome. Would be like a real-world badge basically, one that you could wear. Of course, they could also create *real badges*.

Comment: In addition to t-shirts for top users we got stickers as well.  This was for users on the original trilogy sites a while back.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than a free Stack Overflow shirt for earning a certain amount of reputation or badges, I think that it would be cool to be able to buy a t-shirt that is printed to order and *customized for you*. **Imagine having your badge list on one sleeve and your current reputation** (at the moment you order it) **on the other.** Not only would this make each shirt desirable because it is unique, but also because after some time has passed many people will probably want to "upgrade" their shirt to show off their latest reputation! As a bonus, a small discount could be offered on a t-shirt at each reputation "milestone" (for example, at 1000, 2000, 5000, 10,000, and 20,000).

Comment: Imagine having a live updating reputation counter on your sleeve. That'd be cooler :P

Comment: Jon Skeet would have to grow some more arms to have enough sleeve to accomodate all his badges

Comment: I was just thinking that he'd need shirts with *really long sleeves*.