# Do anyone dissapoiint the achievement rules of Stack network?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

I am curious why Stack Network can't count all websites' achievements together. If someone has many stack websites, it will not show all points of a contributor. It sounds that it's a waste of time to level up for other insignificant websites. The question differs from [Unify reputation across multiple accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246614/unify-reputation-across-multiple-accounts). In my opinion, it's strange to bound the site together on the menu but counts achievement separately.

Comment: (subjective personal opinion) The trick of the system is that the last really useable privilege is coming at 3k. So you can close or reopen questions. Privileges over it are little and don't deserve their price. If you want to have the largest impact, get to 3k on so many sites as you can.

Comment: I realized that I can register for different sites. But I don't get the sense that bound the sites together on the menu.

Comment: @LyuJyun-Hong the sites are bound together to: 1) Show you they're all part of the same network, and 2) Allow easy navigation between the sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achievements aren’t synced across all sites.

Achievements show your knowledge so if you know a lot on Site A and not a lot on Site B there’s not really a point as it would be:

- **Confusing**, people thinking what Site you earned it on.
- **Misleading**, people thinking you are an expert on the subject when you’re not.
- **Unworthy**, you feel proud of achievements on a specific site and not just I got this on B because I got it on A. You also didn’t do anything to get that achievement on Site B but just click a button and register.

You can view a list of all accounts including reputation and badges on stackexchange.com and clicking your profile and then accounts.

You will be able to see all accounts the number of different types of badges earned and feel truly proud.

Comment: I don't like the forum system because I can't ask any question such as this post. Then I will get a lot of negative reputation. It completely differs from the Reddit forum. Do any tags for newbie to ask a question?

Comment: @LyuJyun-Hong No, there are no such tags. Tags like [newbie] are known as “meta tags” around here, and they’re disallowed. More broadly, it is very hard to ask “newbie” type questions around here. The questions which get upvotes are new, interesting Qs that haven’t gotten answers before and are difficult to answer just by googling (and where the OP has *proven* that they haven’t been hard before and are not easy to answer with google by *showing he already did the SE and google searches before asking*, in the body of his question).

Comment: @Joseph - Stack Exchange communities are specifically NOT a forum.  Your lack of reputation does not prevent you from asking a good question.  Your lack of reputation does not prevent you from submitting a quality answer.  The only time a lack of reputation prevents you from doing something is answering a question, that has been protected and that is a single upvote away (10 reputation).

Comment: No doubt Stack Exchange used forum system. People can ask or answer a question either on Stack or other forums such as Quora. The biggest difference is that someone who build a rule initially that prevents forum style on Stack websites. It's more likely a hiring system to me.