# Stack Overflow Mug

Tags: discussion, fun, swag

A friend got me a stack overflow mug and its amazing - but one thing has always troubled me.

Is the code written in a real world language? The code seems like it could be improved slightly.

```
if (owner.isCoding() && mug.isEmpty()){
    mug.fill('coffee');
}
```

[image]

It appears to me that `isCoding` and `isEmpty` are methods but could possibly be properties on an object to save checking the conditions each time.

Also wouldn't it be safer for the `fill` method on mug to expect a parameter with a type other than string.

Comment: where can i get that mug?

Comment: I was going to link to the shop http://shop.stackexchange.com/password but it seems it been closed?

Comment: Meh. Looks like Java.

Comment: @benni_mac_b [What happened to the Stack Exchange store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store)

Comment: I think you drank one too many cups... ;)

Comment: The single quotes around `'coffee'` wouldn't compile in Java.

Comment: I first thought too that it looks like Java. Well, it is not C#...could be JavaScript. On the other hand, wouldn't it be better if `'coffee'` would be extracted into an Enum (if the language supports it)? I always at those "magical strings", as they are the same for me as "magical numbers"...

Comment: What, you don't like my coding style? My suggestion was the basis for what's on the mug, with some editing by others if I recall, but I can't find the post where I suggested it. I think it's now been deleted. At least they sent me a free mug for using my idea. It's currently full of pistachio shells. ;)

Comment: Have at the source http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/what-types-of-stack-overflow-schwag-would-you-like-to-see/14274#14274 @gno

Comment: @random that's a 404 for me.  Deleted page?

Comment: @gnostradamus amazing, I was hoping the author would appear. Would love to see the other suggestions

Comment: [Here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qULts.png) of the original suggestion, with its comments... probably not as exciting as you're expecting it to be. It was an answer to "What types of Stack Overflow schwag would you like to see?"

Comment: The string `coffee` should be enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes, thereby adding at least C and C++ to the list of languages in which the code is legal.

Comment: looks like javascript 8)

Comment: I'm working remote now, and needed a quick image to show to my coworkers of one of my most prized possessions.  Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As the owner of such a mug, I can assure you that the code definitely works; when I'm coding and drinking from that mug, the ingredients are always coffee (at least in the duck-typing sense: it looks like coffee, smells like coffee, and tastes like coffee).

So any objection would purely be regarding the code style, but as they say: If it ain't broke, don't fix it :)

Comment: Mine is filled with water right now.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @BilltheLizard The answer "CoffeeScript" would be too obvious, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ever got a bug in your coffee? Now *that's* nasty.

Answer (score 17):

I'm sorry, this just won't work for me. There should be a `while` loop and an instruction to suspend the current thread until the mug becomes empty again, at which point the *producer* is woken up by the *consumer* to put more coffee in the buffer (mug).

Comment: Just hope it's not a ring buffer, that'll make a mess on your desk.

Answer (score 2):

Its not effing C#, which offends me.