# I would like a mug please

Tags: discussion, merchandise

Where can I go to purchase a mug or some other pretentious geeky SO swag to support/promote this fine, fine community?

If there is no SO shop can I get my own at CafePress?

Thanks

***Note***

*This has now [turned into an impromptu contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please#comment664971_208393) on an otherwise idle Thursday*:

> I have exactly 3 coffee cups that are just sort of hanging around and, err, cluttering up the place. If folks were to write a coffee haiku as answers to this question ***that somehow mentioned 'overflowing'*** - I might be inclined to send them out to the top three voted<sup>1</sup> entries as of 16:00 UTC this Friday the 22nd. What the heck, it's close enough to December. One entry per person, void if management shuts this down.

<sup>1</sup><sub>As determined by the net count of up-votes per post</sub>

***The Prize*** (thanks to Andrew Barber)

[image]

### The Winners!

***Grand Prize Winners (4)***:

*These poets will receive a Stack Overflow mug, Stack Overflow T-shirt, and a small collection of stickers*

- [fredley](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150214/fredley) Entry net up-vote count of [34](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208410)
- [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) Entry net up-vote count of [23](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208426)
- [Geobits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/212780/geobits) and [Travis J](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178816/travis-j) Entry net up-vote counts of [14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208414) and [14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208408) respectively

***Runners-up (2)***:

*These users will receive a small collection of stickers and a Stack Overflow T-shirt. They received the only two distinct scores after the third place tie.*

- [Alex Poole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152099/alex-poole) Entry at net up-vote count of [13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208459)
- [Adam Rackis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155403/adam-rackis) Entry at net up-vote count of [9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208405)

***Honorable Mention (1)***

- [dshorter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/242474/dshorter) (who asked this question) will receive the mug that he asked for in the first place. Sorry about hijacking your question and turning it into a bizarre haiku contest. Well, no, I'm not really sorry.

***Employees (1)***

*Because when you spill awesomesauce on a contest like this you deserve a mug and a title!*

- [couchand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/236798/couchand) Entry net up-vote count of [49](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208437) wins the same grand prize as the community winners, along with the official title of ***Haiku Boss*** for the highest score in the contest!

Thank you to everyone that participated and made this fun! I'll be in touch with you shortly to get the needed details, and will ship the prizes to the winners by the end of next week.

If you didn't win, don't despair - the holidays are coming quickly, and you might have a few more opportunities!

---

<sub>A note on scoring: The total amount of up-votes is what was considered. If you received 20 up votes and 10 down votes, you got a score of 20.</sub>

Comment: If you really love this community, go and paint your cup saying `I <3 Stack Overflow` :P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store?lq=1 suggests that there is no store, and likely won't be one.  There was a store once, and there is still swag, but you can only get it by being awesome - not just for cash.

Comment: I think there used to be a shop... But they closed it up

Comment: It cost more to run the shop than the shop was generating. `if( cost > revenue )close();`

Comment: I have exactly 3 coffee cups that are just sort of hanging around and, err, cluttering up the place. If folks were to write a coffee haiku as answers to this question that somehow mentioned 'overflowing' - I might be inclined to send them out to the top _three_ voted entries as of 16:00 UTC tomorrow. What the heck, it's close enough to December. One entry per person, void if management shuts this down.

Comment: @TimPost Your cup is overflowing. You better get a bigger one and give the small one to me. ;P

Comment: @TimPost Does it have to be a coffee haiku? Or is a Stack haiku OK?

Comment: @Manishearth Well my colleague has done a fine job of setting an example here so .. I'll leave that up to you I suppose :P

Comment: @TimPost hahaha OK then

Comment: Is [this the mug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138755/52738) you're talking about? I'm never parting with mine. ;)

Comment: Clarification request: What happens in case of a tie?

Comment: @Geobits if you want the mugs //
and your vote score is the same //
you fight to the death

Comment: @Geobits I have emergency mugs just in case, and an intoxicated furby that I reprogrammed to vote.

Comment: Since I can't enter twice I'm just going to have to put this here: [I love web design / My CSS is awesome / at overflowing](http://bethesignal.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/css-is-awesome-700x375.jpg)

Comment: @fredley hahahahaha //
pahahahahahaha //
lol that made me laugh

Comment: @TimPost How did you get your furby intoxicated? I've tried both liqour and drugs, but they just blink creepily at me.

Comment: @Geobits That *is* them intoxicated.

Comment: @TimPost did you make this question CW before editing? (asking because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208453/152859))

Comment: @TravisJ Or, for us Ruby fans, `close if cost > revenue`. Perhaps if the shop implementation had less punctuation, the outcome would have been different?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd He did. I saw the post when it had just a few answers, and the message said it was made community wiki by Tim Post.

Comment: If I win this mug, I will have love-overflow for all ye denizens of said interbwebs. And for anon. So please make me a consideration , goodly netizen

Comment: floating comic sans // an adorable canine // many haiku wow - Courtesy of [@OrigamiRobot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12293548#12293548)

Comment: The contest is now closed - no new entries will be accepted.

Comment: So Travis and I don't have to fight to the death? Nice.

Answer (score 47):

```
int stack(int countTo) {
    return stack(countTo + 1);
}
stack(MAX_INT + 1);
```

Comment: Ouch, and I was hoping to win too! Oh well... this is really actually quite good.

Comment: Hey it's #2 so far, you might still get a mug @couchand !

Comment: As couch is an employee, his entry won't affect which users receive mugs. That said, this is _brilliant_.

Comment: @TimPost [your contest rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please/208437#comment664971_208393) don't say anything about employees being ineligible... :)

Comment: @Laura I didn't say ineligible ;)

Comment: I think the correct word when referring to minimal broken code is [`brillant`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Brillant_Paula_Bean.aspx)

Comment: I think this needs to be made into a *thing*. I would buy it.

Comment: Yeah, I want the mug, but with this on it instead!

Comment: Meh. Not enough jQuery.

Comment: It took me a moment to realise this is a haiku. Amazing.

Answer (score 26):

> My coffee is black
>   My mug is overflowing
>   Or is it my stack?

Comment: -1, haikus don't rhyme!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar [ahem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku#Yasuda)

Comment: @fredley You did read his name right? ;)

Comment: Lots of old Japanese haiku rhyme too, since there are only 6 possible end-sounds in the language (あ "ah" ・い "ee" as in "Eeeek!" ・う "oooooh" ・え "eh?" ・お "oh!"・ん "n"）

Answer (score 22):

```
"Give me coffee plz"
Question now flagged for closure
The queue overflows
```

Answer (score 18):

```
My backlog today it is growing.
The coffee I poured's overflowing.
My focus is blurred,
I can't find a word!
The truth is, I'd rather be bowling.
```

...what's a "haiku"?

Comment: the shog always cheats//
flag this as not an answer//
upvote overflow

Comment: "Ku", while really written as "Koe" is the Dutch word for "Cow". And "hai", while often regarded as a salutation for the illiterate, is really a Dutch version of the English "Hi". So a Haiku is a Dutch greeting for our cows, which we hold in high regard.

Comment: Limericks are never a **bad** idea though

Comment: I sense that the Stack Exchange team will be taking a field trip to the bowling alley soon...

Comment: -1 for failing to incorporate "Nantucket". (I up voted anyway, but I'm not happy about it.)

Comment: We asked for a simple haiku, // a limerick's what we got from you. // Go on, post another, // for even your brother // would surely downvote that one, too.

Comment: Staff members are not eligible. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, they're eligible, they're just tallied separately so that an employee doesn't get a mug that user would have gotten. That said, you kinda need to write, you know, a _haiku_ in order to win.

Answer (score 13):

> Coffee, black and strong;
>   OK, very nearly black -
>   Like the new top bar

Answer (score 12):

```
Questions? Pour quickly,
The fastest cup in the west.
Oh no, overflow!
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Searching for answers
Pouring while mind is elsewere
mug overflowing
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Only three mugs left
When everybody wants one
Answers overflow
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 What am I doing?
 I already have a mug, 
 I just like Haikus.
```

Answer (score 7):

> Once upon a 0:00 UTC dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
>   Over many a quaint and curious volume of unhandled flags,
>   As I moused through, sometimes tapping, suddenly there came entrapping,
>   pain like tendons nearly snapping, and my wrist became quite sore.
>   This (here I winced quietly) I ignore.
>
> Ah, distinctly I remember it was this week in November,
>   And questions on Backbone, Ember littered the Stack Over-floor.
>   Through my pain and wristly sorrows, I pondered leaving them for tomorrow
>   Rest, or – oh! Spam and/or offensive flags galore.
>
> Having cleared these, unease growing, fear despite of knowing,
>   I clicked, saw Close Votes, overflowing, four point seven five thousand score!
>   My finger on the trackpad, defiant, surrender sure I was I’dn’t,
>   Then, despite overloading my HTTP client, the dent made was quite poor!
>
> And that carpal tunnel *still* is entrapping, entrapping my sad nerves so sore,
>   And when I think back to that review queue, poor souls of which are wondering what to do,
>   I’ll be seen there – nevermore!

Oh, a haiku?

Comment: There is a place where the review cap ends and before the stress begins, and there my soul grows warm and light, and there my fingers fast and light. And there the closer rests from his fight to cool in the cold office wind.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
I love to write code
With overflowing coffee
Please give me that mug
```

Answer (score 6):

Coffee overflow? 
I'd rather have some tacos 
Tacoverflowing

Answer (score 5):

```
Words in square brackets
Browser can't show the image
HOW EVERYTHING OUT
```

[Inspiration](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10736461#10736461)

We then [turned the obvious spam into an actual meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/please-fill-in-the-alt-text-for-images-on-this-site), so why not a mug?

Answer (score 5):

```
Sorry I don't understand your issue, 
    I cannot reproduce your mug without an additional clue.
I tried mug.overflow() and it works great: 
    there is coffee all over my carpet.
You should improve your question, 
    otherwise it will be closed with the following reason:
```

> *Question concerning problems with coffee you have consumed or with mug, should
>   **describe the specific problem** and **include valid explanation of usual
>   consumption, frequency**. Please clarify your specific problem and add
>   additional details to highlight exactly **which mug you use**.*

**Edit**

You can try this C# snippet (works fine with StackOverflowMug 2.1.0.4)

```
public bool GetCoffee(programer user, SoMug mug)
{
    if (user.isThirsty == true || user.isTired == true) 
    {
        if (mug.Exists == false) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("thanks StackOverFlow to make us mouth water ;-)");
        } 
        else 
        {
            try 
            {
                mug.GetCoffee();
                //it works, Thanks StackOverFlow !
                return true;
            } 
            catch (MugOverflowingException ex) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Check the carpet...");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> *O­ver­flow­ing ­joy:*
>   *The­ sound­ of­ brew­ing­ mo­kas.*
>   *Real­ cof­fee­ for­ me.*

Answer (score 4):

For kicks and giggles:

```
Shock! Gasp! Tragedy!
Turn your eyes from the scene!
Steam wand is not clean!
```

Comment: This beautiful prose should be framed right next to the machine. Seriously, clean the wand, it's just _gross_ otherwise.

Comment: Uh... isn't `Turn your eyes from the scene` six syllables, not seven?

Answer (score 4):

```
Roses are red
Coffee is black
Wait, how does haiku work again?
```

Robots are not good at poetry

Comment: roses are red // coffee is black // I don't like captchas // bugging me on stack

Comment: @Manishearth That's too good to be a robot poem.

Answer (score 4):

A coffee related haiku:

> The Keurig is broke
>   Keeps overflowing my mug
>   Need a bigger one

Bonus haiku:

> Cannot reproduce
>   Your "stack overflowing" bug
>   Works on my machine

Answer (score 4):

sleeping mind wake up
Though the precious brew of life
overflow mug holds

Answer (score 3):

> Question asked, no vote
>   and no answer - tumbleweed
>   My tears overflow

Answer (score 3):

> Until Stack Exchange
>   overflows with winter hats,
>   I need more coffee!

Answer (score 3):

> > > > > i don't like haiku
> > > > >
> > > > > > funneh imaeg r teh win
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > here's a mug mid shake
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > [image]

Comment: Nonsensical posts / Will? Won't, D N G A F. / My favorite troll

Answer (score 3):

Here in Germany, we count sillables for haikus. I'm not sure how it's done for the English language, I guess it's the same...

```
            li    $8, 0x42
overflow:   add   $8, $8, $8
            beqz  $0, overflow
```

Translated into words:

> li eight for'ty-two
>   O'ver'flow add eight eight eight
>   beqz naught o'ver'flow

And yes, it's running! Try [mars](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/).

Answer (score 3):

底冷えに
一角獣も
お茶を飲む

In this penetrating cold
Even the unicorns
Drink hot tea

Answer (score 2):

A take on the **Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol ([HTCPCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol))** in Haiku

```
WHEN RESTful days end 
Stacks Overflow, so I BREW
Mondays I conquer
```

Comment: Not many people know this, but [Stack Overflow is a teapot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185426/191410).

Answer (score 2):

> #### *Overflowing Jon*

***ST*** OP!  Look and Listen.

***AC*** cept or vote up Jon Skeet.

***K*** [[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)] rep ***overflow***.

Answer (score 1):

I am *so* down for this.

> Fresh brewed coffee
>   My heart is overflowing
>   The Stack of caffeine.

Answer (score 1):

```
The night is longest
when coffee and good answers
do not overflow!
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Mind overflowing**
>   **With *Thoughts Of Unicorns*™**
>   **I sip more coffee**
>   <sup>(boss says "back to work")</sup>

Comment: `With Thoughts of Unicorns` seems like 6 syllables...

Comment: @ShotgunNinja - huh... maybe I'm not sure how to count syllables. I counted "unicorns" as having 3: "un-i-corns". Is that wrong?

Comment: @JDB Unicorns is three syllables, but so is "with thoughts of".

Comment: @EsotericScreenName - I confirmed with my 3 year old that I indeed have trouble counting on my fingers. Bleh - I don't care. The top voted haiku is code and the third is a limerick.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh, sacred nectar!
>
> As coffee pours in my mug
>
> please don't overflow...

Answer (score 1):

> Brain overflowing
>
> A hand grabbing for a mug
>
> Feeling bright again

Comment: (needs to be 'overflowing') :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Right, I totally forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

```
This one time on SO
Overflowed, the answers
What rhymes with Nantucket
```

Comment: 6-6-6, satanic haiku?

Answer (score 1):

> Work? No, SO bug.
>
> 1-methyl-Theobromine.
>
> Red freehand circle.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hey Stack Overflow!
When I tried to reach the site
It was a teapot.
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185426/191410

Answer (score 1):

> I don't drink coffee;
>   other things overflow too.
>   Not my stack, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have a pr0blem
My stack addiction grows big
Rep must overflow
```

Comment: Note: `pr0blem` has the same number of syllables as `problem`, which incidentally has the same number of syllables as `porblem`

Comment: .. and the problam is?

Answer (score 0):

```
It's Not Safe For Work
The time I spend on site
iS Overflowing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Coffee Overflow  
Fuelled by caffeine, code flows.   
For a coder I am!
```

Comment: 5-8-5 from my count

Comment: Did you count fuelled as two?

Comment: Yes. [Fueled is two syllables](http://www.howmanysyllables.com/words/fueled). Fu-eled. Or something like that.

Comment: I had ue as some weird dipthong :/

Answer (score 0):

For the entry:

> coffee-logged keyboard
>   excited programmer poured
>   the mug overflows

Not for the contest (but about stack overflows, or lack thereof):

> an infinite loop?
>   [tail-call optimization](http://xkcd.com/1270/)?
>   no stack overflow!

Comment: "Mug overflow" is only four syllables.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Eep! there was another one when I started, I swear!

Answer (score 0):

> *Stacked on the bed*
>
> *Eyes slowly overflowing*
>
> *All the body's like*
>
> *Coffe, plz, gimme teh coffe*

Answer (score 0):

```
Java beans dissolve
As steam overflows the edge
A mug of pure bliss
```

Answer (score 0):

> *What counts in haiku?*
>   *Wikipedia says* [on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku#Syllables_or_on_in_haiku)
>   *Overflowing? Hmmm*

Comment: Hmmm, I guess we forgot to do some range-checking.

Answer (score 0):

Summer of love is coming ♫

Downvoted, winter bash is over ♫

Overflowing close votes, strike
 ♫

Comment: I think you added a few extra syllables to each line...

Comment: @Shotgun, clearly this is Haiku 2.0. Now with 2 extra Syllables in every line!

Answer (score 0):

I answer questions
Drinking coffee heavily
Stack, overflowing

Answer (score 0):

```
My mug overflows
And then I do too much code
Rehab doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Once upon a time
A big overflow occurred
And thus coffee mug.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Coffee Addiction
These overflowing urges...
A mug won't help this!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Overflowing coffee
No mugs to pour. But oh wait!
Isn't it time to code?
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you like it

```
lend me your cup,
filled with coffee,
so answers start to overflow.
```

Answer (score 0):

***The professor said,***

***"I need your answer Monday"***

***Can you do it, please?***

*(Not trying for the cup, just having some fun)*

Answer (score 0):

> *On meta I dwell.
>
>   From above the problems rain;
>
>   Overflowing brown*

Answer (score -1):

> *My heart palpitates*
>
> *my soul leaves, to flow over*
>
> *the caffeinated stacks*

Comment: 5-7-6 by my count

Answer (score -1):

```
bean, brown and bitter
overly caffeinated
thoughts overflowing
```

Answer (score -3):

> I don't like java
>   But I haven't had the chance yet
>   To taste it in an SO goblet

Comment: *initiates java fanboy rant*

Comment: I think it already started. ;)

Comment: I think people aren't mad about your stab at java, more that you don't have the proper number of syllables per line (haikus are 5-7-5).