# Scold SO mug printers (or find better ones)

Tags: discussion, merchandise

I am, of course, ecstatic to have been able to join the *Glorious StackOverflow-Mug-Owning Master Race*, but perhaps in future StackExchange should consider using a more reliable printer?

[image]

---

<sup>Just letting you know, I am *in no way* dissatisfied with my mug!</sup>

Comment: hmmm ... you got mugged

Comment: Looks like your text... \*puts.sunglasses.on\* ...is overflowing. *YYYEEEEAAAAAAAHHHHHHH*

Comment: Maybe that had an ink overflow exception?

Comment: Did that happen in the dishwasher? Also, how long have you had the mug? (I've had mine for a while, and that hasn't happened. Could be that they switched suppliers.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Brand new out of the box

Comment: Then maybe the box did that to your mug?

Comment: It's specially tailored to [your haiku](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208410/212780). The middle line was "*My mug is overflowing*".

Comment: My mug is here! // The text is overflowing :( // Complain on meta

Comment: We'll fix it. Now, aren't you glad you have the ultra rare limited print of the SO mug?

Comment: Got mine in the mail today. In a way, I was *slightly* disappointed that it was just a "normal" one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Our Printer is actually pretty amazing and they make ALL of our swag. This must have just slipped by.

We can get another one sent out to you.

Comment: Please don't! I'm not complaining, just wanted to make sure you know, that's all! Being British and facing up to American customer service is awful.

Comment: @fredley ah, but don't forget: yours is now **even more unique and rare** - think of the increased market value!

Comment: @fredley: "Stack Overflow mug with overflowing overflow text, showing how Stack Overflow overflows it's boundaries in the modern, limited internet world and inviting to the viewer to do the same." It's basically modern art!

Comment: I love how just the overflow overflowed. If we do send you another, it's only so you can keep that one nice and preserved while actually using one that isn't so special.

Comment: FWIW, the one I just received isn't great either, with a lot of missing ink on the "C" of `isCoding`.  Not worth sending another, though!