# Buy Stack Overflow shirt

Tags: support, swag

Is there any online merchant that is selling shirts with the Stack Overflow logo? I've been searching the web without any success; I'd really be happy to have one!

**Update:**

Seeing that I can't buy the shirt online, is anybody willing to sell one to me (size large)?

Comment: There was a shop, but it's gone now ='(

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store

Comment: Is there any way I could get my hands on a shirt?

Comment: I'll sell you mine for $1000. Sorry, forgot the :-) ... you can't have mine.

Comment: This: http://www.zazzle.com/stack_overflow_t_shirt-235870886400716677

Comment: I want a StackOverflow polo.

Answer (score 3):

No, we do not currently sell or license our trademarks to be sold anywhere online at this time.

Comment: So I'm guessing my only chance it to get one second hand?

Comment: Are you thinking of selling shirts online again?

Comment: I would vote against it. Or at least make them much different. Then we who got in early have some kind of elitist mark. :-)

Comment: Now I regret missing the opportunity to own a trollface superuser coffee mug.

Comment: Does this mean we can't make our own without violating your trademark? I was thinking of just the StackOverflow logo and text in the center.

Comment: -1 until you start telling shirts!

Comment: That's a shame! Stack Overflow shirts are nice swag to show off for any developer. Why not sell them? Or, alternatively, why not allow others to use the logo / trademark and sell them? If you want, you can totally outsource all the work to eg. https://www.spreadshirt.com/ (which sells very high-quality shirts) and still make a profit on them.