# What is the current Stack Overflow t-shirt?

Tags: support, t-shirt

I'm a picky guy, just ask anyone who's ever gone clothes shopping with me.

As such, I won't just wear any old shirt, regardless of the logo.

Now assume for a moment that I was getting a Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow t-shirt. Maybe I hacked a server or two, injected some code to cause any lucky draw to pick my name, there was a lucky draw, my code accidentally caused a stack overflow, injected a fix, there was another draw, and I was completely randomly chosen as the lucky winner of a t-shirt - aren't I lucky? ... or something like that.

Now I have a choice of either a Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow shirt, in either black or white. Because of the above reasons, this quite a conundrum - should I just go with the safe bet and pick the Stack Exchange shirt, or roll the dice on possibly getting a really cool Stack Overflow shirt, or possibly get a shirt that will just hang in the back of my closet for hopelessly too long, or try to figure out what that shirt would actually look like beforehand?

So here I am.

What does the Stack Overflow t-shirt look like? Is there one? Am I allowed to publicly ask what it looks like (or, similarly, are you allowed to publicly tell me)?

Can we perhaps change any offers of a t-shirt to be accompanied by an image of the shirt, if possible?

By the way - based on my Google-foo, I assume the Stack Exchange shirt (at least the black one) looks like this: (correct me if I'm wrong)

[image]

PS - [You can't buy these shirts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store). You can only get them through being special.

Comment: It's a gift to show appreciation and made in good faith... personally I'd be a bit offended if I knew the recipient was so fussy ;-)

Comment: @JonClements I'm fussy - I can't really help any offence caused by the way I am. Being primarily logical and practical, I can't be particularly thankful for a gift I don't want or can't use (but there may be special circumstances) - while this may be considered rude or impolite, that's just the way I am and, being perhaps more honest than is good for me, I'm not going to pretend to be thankful if I'm not. By the way - I think the SE shirt looks great (by normal standards - it's complicated), but I would've liked to (and do now) know what the SO shirt looks like in case it looked even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: black T] [image: white T]

<sub><sup>[Source](https://stackexchange.com/catalog)</sup></sub>

I have a few of the black T-shirts, plus one based on the [famous HTML-with-regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (unicorn shaped!), but I don't think that last one is generally available when you are offered a T-shirt.

Comment: Price tags please? ;)

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: unless I'm mistaken, you can't buy any SE goodies anymore. They are distributed by SE to people themselves for reasons only they know.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but he can pay dear Mr. Pieters directly. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't think even Bill Gates could afford the price tag I've put on mine..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Not even a few million [unicorn dollars](http://imagehost.epier.com/56846/Unicorn%20Million%20Dollars(1).jpg)?;)

Comment: I actually found the image in my question on the same page you found your images, turns out I'm just blind 'cause I managed to miss those two ... or there's a conspiracy against me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not even $19134702400093278081449423917?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Zalgo Unicorn trumps unicorn dollars trumps fibonacci number.

Comment: @Dukeling: I've been told that many items on that page are not available anymore, so the link is not as useful as you'd hope it to be.