# Policy for informing Stack Exchange about illegit Stack Overflow merchandise

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, merchandise

I came across this t-shirt which has Stack Overflow logo on it and is available in various colors and styles.

[image]

This doesn't look legit and I understand from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580/218121) that Stack Exchange store is closed. From [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231915/is-this-university-of-stackoverflow-t-shirt-legit#comment763485_231916) from a Stack Exchange employee I understand that this is against their trademark. Is there a policy that I should follow to report these like there is a [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/218121) for reporting a SCRAPER? or Is a post like this is sufficient?

Answer (score 18):

Since it is up to Stack Exchange, Inc to enforce their trademark, there is little the community can do.  The best course of action is to contact the SE Community team directly via the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer of every page.  Or by emailing them at `team@stackexchange.com`.

The process is probably going to be similar to reporting a scraper since they are going to need most of the same info.

Comment: True, that's what I thought. I want to confirm it with Stack Exchange employee/community manager about the guidelines.

Comment: @Ram Using the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the site is the best option. Thanks.