# Details of limitation on usage of Stack Exchange brandings

Tags: support

I'm currently involved in the creation of a cross-platform media experiment with three or four other people, which will involve a section that's a good natured (I hope!) parody of the Stack Exchange network.

For part of this I hope to use the Stack Exchange API (I'll ask a separate question about that in the Stack Apps Stack).

What I'm wondering is: is there anywhere I can find the full details of all the legalities surrounding usage and licensing of Stack Exchange branding and the like (as derived from that which appears on the software that powers the Stack Exchange network), as this will be a money-making venture and we want to take the time to do things right.

Comment: What exactly does it do?

Comment: It's part of the wider game that simulates and/or utilises well-known elements of the web and social media and injects narrative into them. So, basically, you're playing a story that happens across the internet. Although there's more to it than that, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: And here I was thinking that Stack Exchange is a parody of something.

Comment: It would explain a lot of things... ;)

Comment: Related, slightly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280052/can-i-use-a-spoof-parody-version-of-the-stackoverflow-logo

Comment: @TIPS ever heard of Experts Exchange?

Comment: @Quill that's the parody of a parody, and <insert yet another repeated but slightly funny jokes about that hyphenated site here>.