# What sites have stickers?

Tags: support, swag, stickers

So apparently [you can get Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/09/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/) stickers by sending a self addressed envelope to Stack Exchange, does anyone know if you can get stickers for any other SE sites?

I'd love some [Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) stickers if they're available!

Comment: [Aviation - Top User Swag!](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3063)

Answer (score 3):

I think all graduated sites have stickers of their own, some examples of sites with their own stickers:

- [Raspberry Pi — Top User Swag!](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/712/raspberry-pi-top-user-swag)
- [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/software-recommendations-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)
- [English Language Learners Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/english-language-learners-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)
- [Computer Science — Top User Swag!](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/computer-science-top-user-swag/1280)
- [Math Stack Exchange Top User Swag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/math-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)
- [Music Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/music-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)

Comment: Also, don't forget: [Chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3132/chemistry-top-user-swag).

Comment: @Berry all sites got it, don't think we should post them all here. (There are dozens of graduated sites)

Comment: Ah, got too hasty with my comment, didn't notice *some examples*. Alright!

Comment: @Arulkumar there is limit of 5, to prevent overload, so I just put the last one manually now. :/

Comment: I take it these can be requested instead of the SO stickers then?

Comment: @Notts90 good question, not sure about that.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137579/195817#137580 "What happened to the Stack Exchange Store?") seems to suggest that swag is now available only as an award for “being awesome”, and not for sale. It’s not clear how that relates to the trilogy stickers.

Comment: May want to add Arqade as an example, since it's one of the most popular sites on SE